# Why does the transition execute instantly when hovered while in animation?

Tags: html, css

```css
@keyframes rightup {
    0% {
        transform-origin: top left;
    }

    5%,
    30% {
        transition: transform 1s ease-out;
        transform-origin: top left;
        transform: rotate(-20deg);
    }

    10%,
    35% {
        transition: transform 1s ease-in;
        transform: translateY(-20px);
    }

    15%,
    40% {
        transition: transform 1s ease-out;
        transform-origin: top right;
        transform: rotate(20deg);
    }

    20%,
    45% {
        transition: transform 1s ease-in;
        transform: translateY(-20px);
    }

    25%,
    50% {
        transform-origin: 0 0;
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
}

body {

    background-color: #82AAE3;
    /*#91D8E4*/

}



.box {

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 110px;


}

.giftbox {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #DC3535;

}

.lid {
    position: absolute;

    height: 20px;
    width: 110px;
    background-color: #DC3535;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 0.1px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    animation-name: rightup;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: 3;
    animation-delay: 1s;

}

.ribbon-h {
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    top: 40%;
    left:0;
    background-color: #FFE15D;
}

.ribbon-v {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 20px;
    left: 40%;
    top:0;
    background-color: #FFE15D;
}

.box:hover {
    transition: transform 400ms ease-in-out;
    transform: scale(1.3);

}

.box:hover .lid {
    animation:none;
    transition: transform 400ms ease-in-out;
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: rotate(-120deg);

}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    
    <div class="giftbox">
        <div class="textmsg"><p></p></div>
        <div class="ribbon-h">
        </div>
        <div class="ribbon-v">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="lid"></div>
</div>
```

When hovered over while the animation is running , the transition mentioned in hover state executes instantly.
While when hovered over after the animation is done , the transition mentioned in hover state executes according to the duration specified.
tried adding play-state:paused too , but that made it even weirder.

Comment: I don’t see this. What browser/OS are you using?

Comment: chrome/windows? idk ,when i run the snippet here , runs fine

Comment: The snippet system adds stuff like !document if it isn't already there. When running it not in the snippet system exactly what code are you running?

Comment: ( https://www.codeply.com/p/5bqkfuj74d ) , this , my bad should have included this from the beginning.